# I am running into an error while importing Spacy

Tags: spacy

When I try to import spacy in python 3.9, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject
```

Not really sure what's going on here. I have installed the package using pip, and updated my numpy as well. I am running my python file in TensorFlow env.

Any solutions?

Comment: Have you installed all packages in the same env ? Seems to be environment collision. Have you checked this out ? https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/5270

Comment: What OS/platform/architecture is this? Is it something other than `x86_64`, or are you compiling spacy packages from source on purpose (with `--no-binary`)? What version of `tensorflow`?

Comment: Issues Resolved, I was installing this on my TensorFlow env ( version 2.8). Some issues with pip installation. Installed using conda and it worked.